# What is this encryption type?

Tags: encryption, encoding, hash, hashcode

I have these two encoded strings but I can't figure it out what type of encryption was used to encode:

> lgGggAJp03czFtABAQAbAGlzU2FsZT1GYWxzZSNwcm9kdWN0SWQ9MTAwMQEBARXgQOoQm2IxgpYaAMcu5PS9BxkOQ7H6ezQsZZ4LjqHl5qOQgJQAESr3N5xVvZ5MCg==

and this:

> b/d19ASvboAn5QBDCVieHoNTokXm0EaJKcSfrgwPlKykTKcIf7hhAibrCYuP0fK8dLH0SKvF6JWuZUftc7bG8wsVhn1uHX5Q4A6VR3POJ8zdbhiHkTcgQwG8wYYpsP3Vn8hLuoOrZbj6FAqO76GkrBYVfDYyF7GYHXdtBZQm4Dk=

I used base64 but it doesn't work.

Comment: If this question is answerable, the internet is doomed to be insecure.

Comment: First one seems to be Base64 to (maybe) Unicode - second one seems to be regular Perl code :) (hahahaha, just kidding)

Comment: Base64 is ***not*** an encryption ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Base64 to me.  Any time I see encoding ending with '=' or '==' it is my first guess.  I can see 'sales' and 'product id' after decoding your first example though it isn't completely readable.  May be double encoded or have other non-printable characters as field delimiters.   Hopefully this gets you heading in the right direction.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that have no place on the site. Even it is the correct answer, this doesn't benefit future readers. Asking to identify an encoding is not a programming question. This question will soon be closed (4/5 votes).

Comment: i attempt to decode this two Snippets but i didnt see any 'sales' and 'product id' in any of them, plz explain more on how to decode this, in c# i use this code to decode from base64:
            'byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(ENCRYPTEDstr);'
            'DECRYPTEDstr = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);'

Comment: If you go to http://www.whatsmyip.org/string-encoder-decoder/ and choose Base64 decode you will see what I described earlier.